# comparing two maps using guava,getting error The method difference(Map<String,Object>, Map<String,Object>) is undefined for the type Maps

Tags: java, maps, comparison, guava, difference

I am comparing two maps using guava,but while comparing I am getting below error for the last line of code snippet.

The method difference(Map, Map) is undefined for the type Maps

**code snippet:**

```
import com.google.common.collect.MapDifference;
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;
public class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        Map<String,Object> map1 = new HashMap <String,Object>();
        Map<String,Object> map2 = new HashMap <String,Object>();

        map1.put("iamt",20);
        map1.put("csamt",25);
        map1.put("camt",30);
        map1.put("samt",35);

        map2.put("csamt",25);
        map2.put("camt",30);
        map2.put("samt",67);
        map2.put("taxval",40);

        MapDifference<String,Object> diff = Maps.difference(map1, map2);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: there should not be any compilation error.Am I missing any import?

Comment: For me, it compiles as is. Most probably you're having an old Guava version on your class path. Did autocomplete work for you?

Comment: I update Guava version,and code compiles without any error.Thanks